# Swipebox hideBarsDelay not working and dynamic Gallery options

Tags: jquery, mobile, gallery, lightbox

I've trying to stop hiding bars and captions with the options given in the documentation but they still disappear, have someone fixed this? also can't figure out how to use the options in a dynamically loaded gallery, my code is:

I use this to launch the gallery:

```
<a id="smPilotos1" title="Casino Plaza - Piloto Classic"><img src="htt://www.llanoriente.cl/img/galeria/llano-oriente-11-tn.jpg" class="th radius" alt="Casino Plaza - Piloto Classic"></a>
```

And I use this to fire the Gallery:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {

  /* Basic Gallery */
  $( '.swipebox' ).swipebox({
    useCSS : true, // false will force the use of jQuery for animations
    hideBarsDelay : 0 // 0 to always show caption and action bar
  });


  /* Dynamic Gallery */
  $( '#smPilotos1' ).click( function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.swipebox( [
    { href:'img/galeria/llano-oriente-11-big.jpg', title:'Loop Wall Depto. 1D 1B' },
    { href:'img/galeria/llano-oriente-12-big.jpg', title:'Living Comedor Depto. 1D 1B' },
    { href:'img/galeria/llano-oriente-13-big.jpg', title:'Dormitorio en Suite Depto. 1D 1B' },
    ] ); 
  } );

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

This stumped me a bit. The docs don't speak to setting defaults for dynamic galleries, but the source code reveals the answer:

```
$.swipebox = function( elem, options ) { ...
```

So you must pass your array of slides followed by an object of any default overrides. Your code should look like this:

```
/* Dynamic Gallery */
$( '#smPilotos1' ).click( function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.swipebox(
        [
            { href:'img/galeria/llano-oriente-11-big.jpg', title:'Loop Wall Depto. 1D 1B' },
            { href:'img/galeria/llano-oriente-12-big.jpg', title:'Living Comedor Depto. 1D 1B' },
            { href:'img/galeria/llano-oriente-13-big.jpg', title:'Dormitorio en Suite Depto. 1D 1B' },
        ],
        {
            useCSS : true, // false will force the use of jQuery for animations
            hideBarsDelay : 0 // 0 to always show caption and action bar
        }    
    ); 
} );
```